# Are there unviewable flying / dark / steel type backgrounds in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever you bring up the screen where you can power up / evolve your pokémon, the currently selected pokémon is shown against a background up top (excuse me for not bringing any images for this). If you pay close attention, you'll notice that the background actually changes depending on what type the pokémon is. For example:

- Bug types get spider webs,
- Fire types get flames / embers,
- Psychic types get a, um, psychedelic background?
- Rock types get a mountainous background,
- Electric types get electric zaps running along,
- etc.

Now, I have caught many pokémon, hence seen the backgrounds of most types, in particular all of them except flying, dark and steel. There are no dark types among the original 151, the Magnemite line get the electric background, and the only pure flying type in the entire series (Tornadus of gen V) won't be introduced in the game for quite a while. Every flying type currently in the game is dual-typed and gets the backgrounds of its other (non-flying) type, so I have yet to see any flying type background.

Do the flying / dark / steel backgrounds exist in the game, waiting until the likes of Umbreon, Tornadus and Registeel are released? The fairy type background exists and is visible for e.g. Clefairy, so arguments based on generational issues seem unlikely to properly answer this question. Are there also any (presumably hacked / mined / extracted) images of these backgrounds to have a look at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the [Generation II](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-021617) release, the "Dark" and "Steel" type backgrounds were added to the mix, and "Flying" was added with the release of [Tornadus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tornadus_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

**Steel**

[image: Screenshot of Skamory]

**Dark**

[image: Screenshot of Murkrow]

**Flying**

[image: Screenshot of Tornadus]

Answer (score 2):

Through game datamining, I have been unable to (as of yet) find any semblance of backgrounds for any of the Dark/Flying/Steel backgrounds.

However, knowing Niantic and their method of operation, they likely do have these assets ready (but not packaged in the game yet), but are just waiting for them to become useful -- as in, there actually being Pokemon of primarily those respective types.

Comment: …aww, I've checked Bulbapedia for the earliest occurrences of pure steel/dark/flying types, so I guess that means we have to wait for Umbreon (gen II), Registeel (gen III) and Tornadus (gen V) respectively to come into play for this to happen. Well, thank you for your hard work and answer.

Answer (score -1):

There's no backgrounds available just yet. I've heard that when the next pokemon generation comes out more types of backgrounds will be unveiled.

Also, I don't think there are images of the backgrounds available yet. Probably the closer we get to the update, the more images will get leaked.

Comment: You "heard" from where?  Can you provide a source?

Comment: I read it from an article that a pokemon go fan page on twitter post, let me see if I can find the twitter account and the article and then I can post it here